# Is there a name for this kind of sentence structure where a clause is in subject position and **it** appears anaphorically in the matrix clause?

Tags: terminology, clauses, middle-english, extraposition

An early 15th century example of a clause deployed in subject position but with an anaphoric **it** as object of the verb in the matrix clause:

> Þat þe sones of pore men gouernen may riche remes, telle it for no tyþingges, for it is no nouelte.
>
> which I would translate/modernize as:
>
> *That the sons of poor men may govern rich realms, don't report it as news, as it is no novelty.*

[a1425 *A Late Middle English Version of Petrarch's De Remediis*, ed. F. N. M. Diekstra (1968)] cited in the MED; see  [**that** conj. 9(b)](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED45063/track?counter=3&search_id=33826402).

Is there a name given to that type of clause structure? It's like the inverse of *extraposition*.

Comment: I'm not sure that's grammatical nowadays. It certainly doesn't sound natural. 'Don't suggest it as something strange that the sons of poor men may rise to prominent positions' defers the referent of 'it' as usual.

Comment: It's called a left dislocation. There's nothing special in particular about the *it* there, I don't think. It's the same kind of construction as *That dog, I don't like it* or *Your Dad, he's the best!*

Comment: @Araucaria Twinning it with a that-clause fronted rather than a regular NP is stretching normal limits.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him  Yes, I suppose the clause boils down to a NP on a semantic level, to the assertion or fact of the fronted/dislocated clause. Such *that*-clauses, standing in isolation, often serve as topics/bullet points for discussion in philosophical and legal texts.

Comment: That's the general practice with anaphors. Clauses are NPs whenever we choose them to be, as long as they're dressed correctly. Like with complementizers or prepositions.

Comment: We can't be 100% sure of the translation. so there's little point in trying to parse it.

Comment: @BillJ: Is my own sentence then (in italics) when taken in its own right without regard for an original, a "left dislocation" in your view as well?  It is like "Don't say it's news that human beings are descended from apes, as it is not news." except with the *that*-clause in subject position: "That human beings are descended from apes, don't say it's news, as it is not news."

Comment: Or, to use a variation of Araucaria's example, "That your dad's the best, don't say it, as he will get a swollen head."

Comment: To me, it looks like a case of object extraposition. The non-extraposed version would be  _Don't report that the sons of poor men may govern rich realms as news_.

Comment: Would **it** in the matrix clause be considered a "dummy"?

Comment: The first "it" as object of "report", yes. But to complicate things, I'd say that the _that_ clause is preposed.

Comment: Could you say a little about the authorship of this sentence?  The construction, unfamiliar as it is in English, is quite familiar in Latin, with which the most prolific writers in the middle ages were monks or scholars of some kind.  Latin composition often orders its sentences as 'topic' (what is being talked about rather than grammatical subject) followed by 'predicate' (what is being said about it).  This sentence looks, in that sense, very Latin, even though it is written in English.

Comment: @Tuffy: Anonymous, presumed  to have been a cleric.  Late 14th / early 15th c. manuscript in an insular hand, containing a variety of devotional and religious works. This work per Diekstra is a "a   cursory   paraphrase,  with  additions  and  omissions,  of  the  first  ten  dialogues  of  the  *De    Remediis    Utriusque  Fortunae*  of  Petrarch, which he finished in 1366.

Comment: @TimR There really seems little point in trying to analyse it any further.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something here but

**That the sons of poor men may govern rich realms,** = content clause – the clause expands on the content of the anaphoric “it” in both clauses.

**don't report it as news,** Main clause in imperative.

**as it is no novelty.** = free modifier

As **it** is no novelty, don't report **it** as news, **that the sons of poor men may govern rich realms.**

Comment: I wanted to know what the current terminology was for such a clause structure. I will add the terminology tag.

Comment: Why should there be a term for it? It is quite unremarkable.

Comment: Its very unremarkability is what makes it nameworthy.  It-cleft got a name, no?